# Cannot enable any extension in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, themes, ubuntu-22.04

i don't know exactly when but my extension has stopped working. i can't activate any extension that i downloaded manually. my biggest problem is that i can't activate user themes, and i can't change the general theme of my linux.

[extensions print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvOq7.png)

if i install the extension-manager, i can install the user themes but no theme is applied.

i tried to install a extension that manage themes but it cant be enabled